# How to return JSON Object from PHP to read from Android App

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have the following `MySQL` table.

[image]

I need to send the dealer name from `android` app and send all matching rows to the app.I dont know how to set the `php` output.I know i should encode using `json_encode(array('stuff'));`

But i dont know how to format the data.Been checking http://www.w3schools.com/json/ It shows an example

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

Should i use the same format?How to read this from android ?Im referring http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php

EDIT:

```
    <?php

  //$con goes here 
    $result=$conn->query("SELECT pname FROM products");
    $response["stuff"] = array();

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())    {

            $stuff= array();

            /* ADD THE TABLE COLUMNS TO THE JSON OBJECT CONTENTS */
            $stuff["pname"] = $row['pname'];
            array_push($response["stuff"], $stuff);

            // $response[] = $row;
        }
        // success
        $response["success"] = 1;
        echo(json_encode($response));


    /* CLOSE THE CONNECTION */
    mysqli_close($conn );
    ?>
```

JAVA Code:

```
package com.example.testing;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

class testing extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>   {
    JSONParser jParser; 
    String URL_TO_PHP = "http://coolsite.com/dashboard/test.php";
    String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    String TAG_STUFF = "stuff";

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {

        /* Building Parameters */
        List <NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        /* getting JSON string from URL */
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_TO_PHP, "GET", params);

        try {
            /* Checking for SUCCESS TAG */
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                JSONArray JAStuff = json.getJSONArray(TAG_STUFF);

                /** CHECK THE NUMBER OF RECORDS **/
                int intStuff = JAStuff.length();

                if (intStuff != 0)  {

                    for (int i = 0; i < JAStuff.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject JOStuff = JAStuff.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.e("ALL THE STUFF", JOStuff.toString());

                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

***Main activity***

```
package com.example.testing;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
          new testing().execute();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }


}
```

***Manifest***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testing"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

***JSON Response in PHP***

```
{"stuff":[{"pname":"Advocates"},{"pname":"Notaries"},{"pname":"Agriculture \/ Fertilizer"},{"pname":"Airconditioners"},{"pname":"Animation"},{"pname":"Airline Companies"},{"pname":"Aluminium Fabricators"},{"pname":"Amusement Parks"},{"pname":"Pets shop"},{"pname":"Association \/ Societies"},{"pname":"Astrology"},{"pname":"Attestation Service"},{"pname":"Auditorium"},{"pname":"Automobiles Accessories"},{"pname":"Automobile Dealers"},{"pname":"Ayurveda"},{"pname":"Gifts Articles"},{"pname":"Bags"},{"pname":"Batteries"},{"pname":"Bearings"},{"pname":"Beauty Parlours \/ Spa"},{"pname":"Magazine Dealers"},{"pname":"Building Contractors"},{"pname":"Building Materials"},{"pname":"Cameras"},{"pname":"Cast Iron Products"},{"pname":"Home Delivery"},{"pname":"Cements Wholesale \/ Retail"},{"pname":"Chemicals"},{"pname":"Contractors"},{"pname":"Consultants"},{"pname":"Parcel Services"},{"pname":"Crockery"},{"pname":"Dental Clinics"},{"pname":"Cyber Parks"},{"pname":"Dance School\/Costumes"},{"pname":"Diagnostics Labs& X-Rays"},{"pname":"Distance Education"},{"pname":"Driving Schools"},{"pname":"Dry Cleaners"},{"pname":"DTH Services"},{"pname":"DTP Centers"},{"pname":"Electrical Contractors \/ Services"},{"pname":"Electronics Equipment \/ Servicing"},{"pname":"Coaching Centre"},{"pname":"Event Management"},{"pname":"Fancy \/ Stationery"},{"pname":"Pooja stores"},{"pname":"Food Products"},{"pname":"Foot Wear"},{"pname":"Foreign Exchange"},{"pname":"Furniture shop"},{"pname":"Granites \/ Marbles"},{"pname":"Hospitals \/ Clinics"},{"pname":"Computer Accessories"},{"pname":"Kitchen Cabinets"},{"pname":"Library"},{"pname":"Lights \/ Fittings"},{"pname":"Mobile Phone Accesseries"},{"pname":"Machinery \/ Tools"},{"pname":"Timber Manufacturer"},{"pname":"Real Estate Agents"},{"pname":"Security Services"},{"pname":"Solar Products"},{"pname":"Health & Fitness"},{"pname":"Travel Agencies"},{"pname":"Used Car \/ Bikes"},{"pname":"Waste Management"},{"pname":"Watches & Clocks"},{"pname":"Handicrafts"},{"pname":"Doors & Windows"}],"success":1}
```

Comment: in php you can format your data in json with [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and in Android you can manage Json with [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) and [JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html)

Comment: @TommyTopas I know..but i need an example

Comment: JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(yourJSONString);

Comment: check out the this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you post does not mention a working PHP file, I will include it for the sake of completeness. This could be a long (*long*) post....

So, first. This is an example of a PHP file that is stored with the name **my_test.php** in at this location: `c:\wamp\www\some_folder_name\my_test.php` (*Please see the edit history for the code*)

Now, let me explain the important portions of this PHP. These parameters should be configured to use your settings:

```
$DB_HOST = 'YOUR_IP_ADDRESS';
$DB_UNAME = 'MYSQL_USERNAME';
$DB_PWD = 'MYSQL_USER'S_PASSWORD';
$DB_DATABASE = 'DATABASE_NAME';
```

The IP Address should be either localhost or the IP address of the computer hosting the MySQL database. Preferably an IP address so you can test on physical devices. using **localhost** would work only on Virtual Devices.

Next up is adding the columns to an array that will construct a single record (*row*) in the JSON response. Take a look at this line for example:

```
$stuff["id"] = $row['id'];
```

The `$stuff["id"]` will basically become the *tag* in the resulting JSON Object whereas the `$row['id']` is what indicates the column name from your DB's table. So the `$row["...."]` has to be identical to the column names in the DB table. While the `$stuff["...."]` can be just about anything. As long as it makes sense to you.

This line `echo(json_encode($response));` will *convert* the response into a JSON format.

Now lets look at the Java code. First up in this is a class that will help you parse through the result. It was taken off a tutorial off a website (*I don't remember which*). Just copy an paste the following code in a Java class. No need to change anything in this file. Do give it a good read to understand how it works. I have it named **JSONParser** (*Please see the edit history for the code*):

Finally, how would to actually get the resulting JSON and parse it in an `Activity` / `Fragment`.

I parse the data in an `AsyncTask`, which is required anyway considering you will be performing a network operation. (*Please see the edit history for the code*)

**Points to note in this Java:**

1. This `String URL_TO_PHP = "http://IP_ADDRESS/some_folder_name/my_test.php";` needs to have either an IP address such as *192.168.0.x* or if you are testing on a virtual device, it should be **10.0.2.2**. The earlier (*192..*) won't work on an emulator and the later (*10.0...*) won't work on a physical device.
2. In this: `String TAG_STUFF = "stuff";`, the `"stuff"` corresponds with this from the PHP file:  `$response["stuff"] = array();`. The `TAG_STUFF` should basically use whats in `$response["stuff"]`.

Hope all the above makes sense. Comment if you need help. ;-)

**UPDATED WITH WORKING SOLUTION:**

This is very weird indeed. But, I have a working solution. When using the OP's code, the application indeed crashes. For lack of time to test why it crashes, I am instead posting a solution directly.

First, instead of keeping `testing` as an independent class, create it as an inner class back in the `MainActivity`.

```
class testing extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>   {
....
}
```

Second, declare the variables globally (*the `jParser`, `URL_TO_PHP`, etc*), as against the current declarations before the `onPreExecute()`. See the complete solution below for clarity...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    JSONParser jParser;
    String URL_TO_PHP = "http://testbox.site50.net/test.php";
    String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    String TAG_STUFF = "stuff";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    ....

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                new testing().execute();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    private class testing extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {

            /* Building Parameters */
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();

            /* getting JSON string from URL */
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_TO_PHP, "GET", params);

            try {
                /* Checking for SUCCESS TAG */
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    JSONArray JAStuff = json.getJSONArray(TAG_STUFF);

                    /** CHECK THE NUMBER OF RECORDS **/
                    int intStuff = JAStuff.length();

                    if (intStuff != 0) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < JAStuff.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject JOStuff = JAStuff.getJSONObject(i);
                            Log.e("ALL THE STUFF", JOStuff.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }
}
```

While testing, I also took a screengrab of the results. Here it is:
[image]

Again, because I am stretched a little thin at the moment, I won't be able to go find out what really is causing the crash in the OP's code. But it's intriguing enough to find out..

Comment: Thanks a lot for the long answer,it really helps :) i already have the php file pulling data from the database.Will learn from this answer and incorporate.

Comment: Im also using mysqli. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi have wrote php code in the server side and its printing json object.Added 2 new files JSONParser and testing to the android project.On the button click event i added      new testing().execute(); but the activity stops.I tried putting the ip address that points to my php file,but  my server says page not found when i type the same ip on the browser.. so i replaced the ip with http link.In both cases the app just crashes.Please help

Comment: Thanks for the reply,it already has the internet permission.Why do you need mysql ipaddress the website is hosted on a shared hosting provider and my php json script is located at www.mysite.com/folder/test.php I tried putting the ip address of mysite.com and also tried with full URL address

Comment: and Im testing on phone not virtual device

Comment: Posted the php code... where can i get the java crash log from eclipse

Comment: updated with java code.I opened log cat and then ddms it showed no messages.DDMS said thread updates not enabled for selected client.Please advice

Comment: Im giving localhost in the connection string instead of ip address.The php code is working fine test.php is printing the json response.Please see updated question.But where can i view the json response in eclipse.. ddms is not showing anything.Can i see it in console

Comment: @techno: The logs will be shown in the ddms perspective under logcat. If I had a working copy of eclipse, I would have posted screenshots. However, in the ddms perspective, select your device from the top most left panel. And in the bottom right panel, all your logs will be shown. If the PHP is working fine as you say it does, and I see that there is nothing wrong with the Java code, the logcat should reveal more about the problem.

Comment: @techno: Alternatively, provide a working link to the PHP and I will test at my end. If you should do so, make sure you change your username and password temporarily while I test. Revert to your originals once I am done. This will speed things up a lot faster..

Comment: Thanks this is the link http://testbox.site50.net/test.php .Do you want me to send the project to you?

Comment: @techno: I have updated the my post with a solution. Your code was indeed crashing. I have a workaround which will involve moving your `testing` `AsyncTask` as an inner class in the `MainActivity` as against the way it is currently created. i.e. as an external java class. Also moving the jParser, URL..., etc is essential. Copying the code from the updated part of the post will fix your issues. ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort.. but unfortunately my app is crashing again after making the changes you have mentioned.I have  uploaded the whole  project here http://www.filedropper.com/testing Please help

Comment: @techno: The problems that seem the biggest usually have the simplest of solutions. And it was mighty stupid of me to have missed this simple one. I need a good kick in my rear right now. ;-) Anyway. change this in your declarations from this: `JSONParser jParser;` to `JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();`. I forgot to include the code that initializes the `JSONParser` instance. No other changes should be necessary. Let me know how it goes.. :-)

Comment: Now it works fine.Thanks a lot Siddharth,its me who deserve a kick in the butt :P I wish i could upvote your answer once more.Thanks a lot for helping me understand how JSON - PHP works by writing a long answer.

Comment: @techno: You are welcome. And I am glad I could be of help. And, good luck with your application. Ping me if you need help.. :-)

Comment: Thanks again :) Will ping you if i face any roadblocks.. that can't be lifted by me alone :)

Comment: Im trying  to pass a value to the php script using  List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pname",selectedproduct)); is the right way to do it.Please suggest

Comment: @ Siddharth Lele Im trying to create a cursor from the JSON response.But there is some problem could you take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28940118/adding-columns-to-matrix-cursor-and-showing-column-count-toast-causing-crash/

Comment: here in the php end, the function is just doing an echo by json encoding the response. Now how can I confirm that the response has reached the android end i.e. is there any way to confirm that the the android system has successfully received the json response.

Comment: here in the php end, the function is just doing an echo by json encoding the response. Now how can I confirm that the response has reached the android end i.e. is there any way to confirm that the the android system has successfully received the json response @IceMAN

Comment: @jishan: The check for that are already in the code. The `if (success == 1) {..}` checks for _success_ that is _echoed_ by the php. If there is no _success_, then the app did not get a response from the php.

Comment: I need to check the confirmation in the php end not in java end. I need to confirm that the response reached to the java end and that confirmation is needed in php code. @IceMAN

Comment: @jishan: In that case, I don't know. Php isn't my strongest suit.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example how to use Volley.jar (lib) to parse your JSON.

```
private void makeJsonArrayRequest() {

showpDialog();

JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(urlJsonArry,
        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                try {
                    // Parsing json array response
                    // loop through each json object
                    jsonResponse = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject person = (JSONObject) response
                                .get(i);

                        String name = person.getString("name");
                        String email = person.getString("email");
                        JSONObject phone = person
                                .getJSONObject("phone");
                        String home = phone.getString("home");
                        String mobile = phone.getString("mobile");

                        jsonResponse += "Name: " + name + "\n\n";
                        jsonResponse += "Email: " + email + "\n\n";
                        jsonResponse += "Home: " + home + "\n\n";
                        jsonResponse += "Mobile: " + mobile + "\n\n\n";

                    }

                    txtResponse.setText(jsonResponse);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                hidepDialog();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                hidepDialog();
            }
        });

// Adding request to request queue
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
```

}

from : [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/)

Comment: But a response will include more than one rows

Comment: Its 1 row with few columns

Comment: in my case i need to get more than 1 rows

Comment: okay..but how to do you create the json object at the php side.My code will be like $result=$conn->query("SELECT dealer FROM main WHERE dealer='$dname'");

Comment: sorry dude, im just android developer ) i can ask some one from my office )). Dont forget about link below !

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JSONParser class.It will help to get json value from webBrowser.After this you may use like this:

```
JSONObjcet object=getJSONObject("result");
JSONArray arr=object.getJSONArray("employees");
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
JSONObject obj1=arr.getJSONObject(i);
String firstName=obj1.getString("firstName");
String lastName=obj1.getString("lastName");
}
```

I Hope this one help to you :)

Comment: hmm.. im just a beginner when it comes to json.I really dont understand how you get individual columns.Could you post something specific to the database i have posted