# how can i pass back data from php to android using variables

Tags: java, php, android, sql, httpurlconnection

I have some data that i passed a httpurlconnection to a php script which gets the variables that have been encoded throught the urlencoder, now i want to get a response back from the script i can do this with an echo but that will not solve my problem i want to save data in different variables just like how it is done using the url encoder for the android part and then send those variables back to the android device. How can i accomplish this please. This is the code for sending the data and receiving response

```
 String data = URLEncoder.encode("studentschool","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(getStudentSchool,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                  URLEncoder.encode("studentdepartment","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(getStudentDepartment,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                  URLEncoder.encode("studentcurrentyear", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(getStudentCurrentYear, "UTF-8");

            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String response = " ";
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                response+=line;
            }
            reader.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            inputStream.close();
            return response;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And this is my php

```
require "init.php";

$school = @$_POST["studentschool"];
$department = @$_POST["studentdepartment"];
$school_year = @$_POST["studentcurrentyear"];

$query = "SELECT *
              FROM `users`
              WHERE `school` = '$school'
               AND  `department` = '$department'
               AND  `schoolyear` = '$school_year'
                AND `courserep` = '1' LIMIT 1";

$result= mysqli_query($link,$query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result)> 0){
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  $monday = $row["Monday"];
  $tuesday = $row["Tuesday"];
  $wednesday = $row["Wednesday"];
  $thursday = $row["Thursday"];
  $friday = $row["Friday"];

  echo $monday;
  echo $tuesday;
}
```

Comment: you'd probably be better off encoding the response data using a standard format like JSON or XML which you can easily deserialise in Android, rather than trying to treat the response like some kind of stream. You probably also want to return something (empty object, or error?) in the case where there are no results.

Comment: P.S. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com/ gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli.

Comment: "will secure it later". IMHO It's much easier to write it correctly the first time, then you don't have to re-test it all later after you make the security changes. Plus it gets you into good habits, and also you don't accidentally forget to do it.

Comment: "what i am parsing is already json from the android app". 1) No it isn't, what is passed from Android to PHP is a load of data in URLEncoded querystring format. 2) We're not talking about what Android sends to PHP, we're talking about what PHP returns to Android. At the moment PHP just sends a single line of text containing $monday and $tuesday concatenated together, which is un-parseable, because you can't tell which bit is supposed to be which variable.

Comment: Also as per the example in the answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28761558/how-to-return-json-object-from-php-to-read-from-android-app) there are much nicer ways to make HTTP requests in android than using low-level stream buffering, both for input and output. You're making this more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: I did pass a json to the php, to be stored in the db so since returning it won't be json anymore, i should encode it and use that?

Comment: "I did pass a json to the php". I'll repeat myself - no, you didn't.  If you don't believe me, watch the request in something like Fiddler or Wireshark, it will be url-encoded data, not JSON-encoded data. I mean, the clue is in the function you called - `URLEncoder.encode(...`. If you don't understand the difference, you can easily look it up with examples of each type of formatting.

Comment: But anyway the formatting of the input data is irrelevant to the formatting of the output data, they don't have to be the same. I suggest replacing `echo $monday` and `echo $tuesday` with maybe something like `echo json_encode(array("Monday" => $monday, "Tuesday"));`, if that suits your intended data structure. I can't help you with deserialising it in Android since I don't know that platform, but you can easily google how to deserialise JSON in Android, and/or consult the link already given to you above.

Comment: No. I didn't suggest that at all. Your question asks about the **response** data going from PHP to Android, and my comment above shows how you could send the **response** data from PHP to Android. The format in which you send the **request** data is fine. What I did allude to earlier on is the overall style of code and libraries you're using to create the request (the whole request, not specifically the transmitted data) can be done more simply using HTTP-specific libraries instead of generic I/O streams, as per the many many examples available online of this kind of process.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help